# Error: Invariant failed: You should not use <withRouter(App) /> outside a <Router>

Tags: javascript, reactjs, router, react-router-dom

I'm pretty sure that I am using  in the right place, but I am still getting the error. Any idea why?

**Error: Invariant failed: You should not use <withRouter(App) /> outside a <Router>**

Apologies for the ugly code. I am new to react.

```
 render()
       return (
        <BrowserRouter>
          <div className="App">
    
            <Route path="/" exact render={ 
              (props)=> {
              return(
                <div>
                  <input type='text' onChange={this.formChangeHandler}/>
                  <p><button onClick={ () => this.postData(this.state.message)}>Submit</button></p>   
                </div>
              )}
            }/> 
    
            <Route path="/post" exact render={
              (props)=> {
                  return(
                  <div>
                    <b>SUCCESS!</b>
                  </div>
                )
                }
              }/> 
            </div>
          </BrowserRouter>
      );
     }
    }
    export default withRouter(App);
```

Answer (score 0):

**withRouter**

You can get access to the *history* object’s properties and the closest *'s match* via the withRouter higher-order component. withRouter will pass updated match, location, and history props to the wrapped component whenever it renders.

```html
import React from "react";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import { withRouter } from "react-router";

// A simple component that shows the pathname of the current location
class ShowTheLocation extends React.Component {
  static propTypes = {
    match: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
    location: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
    history: PropTypes.object.isRequired
  };

  render() {
    const { match, location, history } = this.props;

    return <div>You are now at {location.pathname}</div>;
  }
}

// Create a new component that is "connected" (to borrow redux
// terminology) to the router.
const ShowTheLocationWithRouter = withRouter(ShowTheLocation);
```

Answer (score 0):

As your error says, you cannot connect a Component to a Router outside of a Router. And your are trying to connecter yhe Component which renders the Router, to the Router

So You need to do something like this

```js
// Main.js
export default class Main extends PureComponent {
    render (
        <BrowserRouter>
            <App />
        </BrowserRouter>
    )
}
```

```js
// App.js
class App extends PureComponent {
    render (
        <div className="app">
            ...
        </div>
    )
}

export default withRouter(App)
```